# Slack API conversations.replies internal_error

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to get thread replies when somebody posts a message to a private slack channel using the python slack api, but I keep getting the following error:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"internal_error","warning":"missing_charset",
 "response_metadata":{"warnings":["missing_charset"]}}
```

The scopes for my user token are: `channels:history`, `groups:history`, and `chat:write`.

Here's my code:

```
slack_client = WebClient(token='xoxp-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx')

resp = slack_client.api_call(api_method="conversations.replies",
                             json={"channel": 'xxxx',
                                   "ts": received_data['event']['thread_ts'], 
                                   "token": 'xoxp-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'})
```

I get the same error using `curl`:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer xoxp-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' -H "Content-type: application/json"
--data '{"token": "xoxp-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx","ts":"1595895414.009700", "channel": "xxxx"}'
https://slack.com/api/conversations.replies
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use `GET` method

you can add `http_verb="GET"` in parameter to `api_call` method

There is also a `conversations_replies` method that wraps this call

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Here's what my code ended up looking like:

```
slack_client = WebClient(token='xoxp-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx')

resp = slack_client.api_call(api_method="conversations.replies",
                             params={"channel": 'xxxx',
                                   "ts": received_data['event']['thread_ts'], 
                                   "token": 'xoxp-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'},
                             http_verb="GET")
```